# chilkat ftp giving unit test karma an Unexpected character '�' error on a binary file

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, chilkat

I have to create some unit tests with some inherited code.
All the code is in a large file, that eventually needs to be separated.
My `karma-jasmine` unit test pulls in this one large file that references `chilkat_node8_win32`.  My test case is not exercising `chilkat`. I can't seem to exclude `chilkat` from within `karma.config.js`.  The `chilkat` is within the code and not a separate file.

I have operationally setup and successful tested a hello world `karma` unit test.  I then moved onto testing the target code and had a variety of configuration errors.  I'm down to this last one.

After looking around...  I couldn't find any `karma` related units tests with `chilkat`, that wasn't a dead link in `python` or giving my anti-virus an issue (I have red flags on the play).

I have tried excluding the file, but again it didn't work.

I found out later the `chilkat` is a purchased ftp and that the source code is private.  Hence the error in the output of `(Source code omitted for this binary file)`.  I'm not sure if this is the reason preventing `karma` from working, or what.

I'm looking for another breadcrumb trail to follow, or else I will have to  re-plumb some SW pipes to separate the ftp `chilkat` code portion into a separate file in order not to include the `chilkat` dependancy within the unit test code.

Any standard practice feedback is appreciated, as I will need justification for the additional scope-creep.  I view that any FTP test should be a systems test, which is probably why I see nothing about `chilkat` with unit tests.

Thanks in advance.
~Mike

```
#Trimmed down unit test code to demonstrate issue:
const chilkat = require('chilkat_node8_win32');
const ftp = new chilkat.Ftp2();
```

```
#karma.config.js

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    //root path location to resolve paths defined in files and exclude
    basePath: '',
    //files/patterns to exclude from loaded files
    exclude: [ '/**/chilkat.node' ],     // <--- attempt to exclude
...
    webpack: {
      externals: ['pg', 'sqlite3', 'tedious', 'pg-hstore'],
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/i,
            exclude: '/**/chilkat.node',    // <--- attempt to exclude
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      node: { fs: 'empty', child_process: 'empty', dns: 'empty', net: 'empty', tls: 'empty', hstore: 'empty', chilkat_node8_win32: 'empty' }   // <--- attempt to enable
    },
    preprocessors: {
      //add webpack as preprocessor to support require() in test-suits .js files
      './test/*.js': ['webpack']
    },
```

```
Error
$ npm test
...
> karma start karma.conf.js

i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.

START:
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
× ｢wdm｣:
ERROR in ./node_modules/chilkat_node8_win32/chilkat.node 1:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./lib/modules/ABC.js 1:14-44
 @ ./test/test.js
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: The black-box nature of the Chilkat libraries always makes them problematic. If you're really wrestling here there's lots of [options for replacement](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ftp).

Comment: Thanks @tadman for the fast response.